# Hiding markup elements in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, markup, org-mode

There are plenty [structural markup elements](http://orgmode.org/manual/Structural-markup-elements.html#Structural-markup-elements) in org-mode like ***bold*** or */italic/*, but they are visible in the org-mode text, which is good, if the file is intended for export, and bad, if it is intended for semi-WYSIWYG editing. I want to hide these markup symbols, so the ***bold*** becomes **bold**, just like links hide their square brackets.

Is that possible in org-mode out of the box? If not, then please suggest an elisp code, that can solve this problem.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try:

```
(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
```

or set it via customize:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>customize-variable<kbd>RET</kbd>org-hide-emphasis-markers<kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

I like to show/hide these often.  It you want to make it a simple toggle, put this in your `init.el` to get a <kbd>C-c e</kbd> binding:

```lisp
(defun org-toggle-emphasis ()
  "Toggle hiding/showing of org emphasize markers."
  (interactive)
  (if org-hide-emphasis-markers
      (set-variable 'org-hide-emphasis-markers nil)
    (set-variable 'org-hide-emphasis-markers t)))
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c e") 'org-toggle-emphasis)
```

Comment: Is it me or does this require re-visiting the file?

Comment: @A.Blizzard Same problem. I add (org-mode-restart) to the end of this function and now I don't need to refresh to see the change

Comment: @Lesley Lai, also could try toggling `visible-mode`. I found it quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using Spacemacs, you can also toggle this with `M-RET T V` (toggles `space-doc-mode`). It hides org-mode emphasis markers and meta tags, among other things. For a full description, see e.g. `SPC h f space-doc-mode`.