# Display formatted text in org-mode without formatting characters

Tags: emacs, org-mode

For example, to make text bold in Org I have to type like this: `*bold*`. I don't want the asterisks to be displayed. How do I do this?

Comment: as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969617/hiding-markup-elements-in-org-mode ?

Comment: @rvf0068 exactly. Thanks. Please make the comment an answer and link to that SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding markup elements in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969617/hiding-markup-elements-in-org-mode)

Answer (score 3):

```
(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
```

More details here: [Hiding markup elements in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969617/hiding-markup-elements-in-org-mode)